# Subleading soft theorem and gauge invariance

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, research-level, infrared-radiation

I am reading a paper by Burnett-Norman and Kroll, called extension of the Low soft photon theorem (https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.20.86). The authors claim that in order to determine the subleading term in a soft momentum expansion of a radiative (i.e. the one that includes soft radiation) amplitude, one needs to consider emission from both external and internal fermions. To be more specific, if I understand it correctly, the emission from external legs will contribute terms that exhibit the form
$$-\sum_aQ_a\frac{p_a\cdot\epsilon(k)}{p_a\cdot k}k\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial p_a}T(...,p_a-k,...)|_{k=0}$$
where $k$ is the soft momentum, carried by the emitted photon and $p_a$ are the fermion momenta.The emission coming from an internal fermion (and this emission can still correspond to a leading term in the perturbation expansion), on the other hand,corresponds to a term
$$\sum_a\epsilon\cdot\mathcal{M}_a$$
where $\mathcal{M}_a$ correspond to the amplitude regarding the emission by a virtual fermion, with the polarization vector stripped off. Then, the authors claim that if we require the sum of these two terms to be gauge invariant, then we can specify the form of $\mathcal{M}_a$, as $\mathcal{M}_a=\frac{\partial}{\partial p_a}T(...,p_a-k,...)|_{k=0}$.

My question is the following: doesn't summing over all contributions from the external soft emission make our amplitude gauge invariant? In the leading soft theorem for example, the gauge invariance implies charge conservation. Why can it not imply charge conservation here as well? Can someone include a counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subleading soft theorem is not associated to any global symmetry. It is automatically gauge invariant (term by term). The leading soft photon theorem is
$$
A_{n+1} \to \sum_k Q_k \frac{p_k \cdot \epsilon}{p_k \cdot q} A_n
$$
Gauge invariance requires that if I replace $\epsilon \to q$, the amplitude must vanish. This implies
$$
\sum_k Q_k  = 0 
$$
which is the statement of charge conservation.

The subleading soft photon theorem is (I'm not being careful about overall factors)
$$
A_{n+1} \to \text{leading} + \sum_k Q_k \frac{q^\mu \epsilon^\nu J_{\mu\nu} }{ p_k \cdot q } A_n
$$
Due to anti-symmetric of the angular momentum tensor $J_{\mu\nu}$, the second term automatically vanishes when I replace $\epsilon \to q$. There is no new constraint on any of the charges.

Analogously in gravity, the leading and subleading soft theorems are associated to global momentum and angular-momentum conservation. The subsubleading soft theorem is not associated to any new global symmetry.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure... The emission by an internal line is specified by gauge invariance and it then combines with the momentum Taylor expansion to yield the orbital angular momentum operator then??

Comment: @schris38 - yes. More generally, you have to also include the spinning wave-functions so the $J_{\mu\nu}$ here actually contains both the orbital angular momtnum part (which you get from Taylor expansion) and the spin angular momentum (which you get from the polarization tensors for the spinning particles)

Comment: Okay thanks! I have a somewhat unrelated last question. Once, you replied to a question of mine with a comment saying that the momentum Taylor expansion of the $\delta$ funtion is again combined with another term that also originates from gauge invariance, such that the Scattering amplitude is related with the Feynman amplitude in this way $S_{rad}=(2\pi)^4\delta^4(P_{tot}^{i}-P_{tot}^{f})\mathcal{M}_{rad}$. Hence, because the angular momentum acted upon the delta function is zero, then the scattering amplitude is given by this formula. Is it the orbital angular momentum there or the total?

Comment: In the subleading soft theorem, the amplitude $A_n$ in question contains the full scattering amplitude (including the momentum conserving Dirac delta function). However, since $J_{\mu\nu}$ acting on the Dirac delta function is zero, it can also be recast in exactly the same form in terms of the amplitudes $M_n$ which do not contain the Dirac delta function.